# How to set up mocks for a test in a separate file with Vitest/Jest and Testing Library?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, react-testing-library, vite, vitest

I have the following files in a React app with Vitest (which has the same API as Jest):

```
// hooks/useEntities/useEntities.ts

return useEntities() {
    // this hooks send api requests so I will mock it in the test file.
}
```

```
// SomeComponent.tsx
import useEntities from 'hooks/useEntities/useEntities'

function SomeComponent () {
    const entities = useEntities()

    return <div>...</div>
}
```

```
// SomeComponent.test.tsx

vi.mock('hooks/useEntities/useEntities', () => ({ // this mocking seems to work
    default: [...]
}))

describe(...) {
    it(...) {
        render(<SomeComponent />)
    }
}
```

Because I mock a lot of hooks this way. I want to separate the mocking part to a different file, so it can be reused. I've tried to following ways without a success:

```
// init.ts

vi.mock('hooks/useEntities/useEntities', () => ({
    default: [...]
}))
```

```
// SomeComponent.test.tsx => this mocking seems to work

await init()

describe(...) {
    it(...) {
        render(<SomeComponent />)
    }
}
```

also tried this way:

```
// init.ts

vi.mock('hooks/useEntities/useEntities', () => ({
    default: [...]
}))
```

```
// SomeComponent.test.tsx => this mocking seems to work

describe(...) {
    beforeAll(async () => {
        await init()
        await init(vi) // tried the same thing with passing the vi instance to the init function in the separate file
    })
    it(...) {
        render(<SomeComponent />)
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried creating another `__mocks__` folder?
- https://jestjs.io/docs/manual-mocks
- https://vitest.dev/guide/mocking.html#automocking-algorithm

Comment: yes and it didn't work @jchua

Comment: do you happen to be using any Mock Service Workers? As MSWs could be intercepting your mocked data within each test.